# related to cakephp

Tags: cakephp

**http://localhost/cakephp/users**
i got a **error** when i am using this url

**Error**: UsersController could not be found.

**Error**: Create the class UsersController below in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php

**http://localhost/cakephp/app/users/view/register.html**
and when i am using this i got a **error**

**Error**: The action users is not defined in controller AppController

**Error**: Create AppController::users() in file: app/Controller/AppController.php.

so what should i do ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a file named as UsersController.php in app/Controller.

And create a method register in UsersController.php and create a file with `.ctp` extension in app/View/Users/register.ctp.

And you can access this file using: **http://localhost/cakephp/users/register**

[This docs link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions) will surely help you to give the complete understanding of creating actions and their respective view files.

Comment: where i have to declare the array

Comment: It is better to learn CakePHP from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html. Ask anytime incase of problem with your code. :)

Comment: now i am getting this errorCall to a member function create() on a non-object

Comment: and my controller code is as follows     `<?php

class UsersController extends AppController
{
 
 var $name='Users';
 
 function register()
 {
  $this->set('Users', $this->User->find('all'));
  
 }
 function add() 
  {
          if (!empty($this->data))
    {
              if ($this->User->save($this->data)) 
    {
                   $this->Session->setFlash('Your are registered.');
                   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'register'));
                      }
          }
      }
 
} 
?>

`

Comment: Nice. I think you were able to save your data if you are submitting a valid form. Isn't it?

Comment: ya its right but when i load the url  *localhost/cakephp/users/add*
   i got a error Call to a member function create() on a non-object

Comment: and the code of add.ctp is `<h1>Add Category</h1>
 <?php
 echo $form->create('post');
 echo $form->input('name');
 echo $form->end('Save Post');
 ?>`